# Displaying database information in list

Tags: php, mysql

Making a drop down with inserted data users but for some reason it wont echo my usernames. Watched couple of tutorials on youtube and all arent working for me because their doing it on a not good This is what i got..
He wont display anything..

```
function get_users($survey_username){ 
global $connection;
$query = "SELECT * FROM users_survey WHERE username";
$survey_username = mysql_query($query,$connection);
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($survey_username)){
echo $survey_username['username'];

}
```

under here is what im pasting in user_list.php

```
get_users($survey_username);
 $survey_username = '';
if($survey_username != ''){
echo ($survey_username['username']);
    }
```

Thanks in advance,

Armando

Comment: @Armando mysql is deprecated as of 5.5 and you can use mysqli_* since 5.3 I would advise moving to that, https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation

Answer (score 3):

You've got quite a few things wrong here.

First of all, your `SQL` doesn't make sense.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users_survey WHERE username";
```

Should be:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users_survey WHERE username = ?";
```

Then bind the result later. (Look at PDO or mysqli).

For examples sake, (but do not use this ever), you'd be looking for something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users_survey WHERE username = '".$survey_username."'";
```

Second of all, you're using `$surver_username` in the function as a variable, but setting it, rather than calling it/using it.

You're supposed to use it like this (example):

```
function square($x){
  return $x * $x;
}

echo square(7); // returns 45
```

In the `user_list.php` under `get_users` function call,

You instantly set `$surver_username` to `''`, (nothing). Then the `if` statement will always be false because it will always equal `''`.

It should be something like this:

```
get_users($survey_username);
if(isset($survey_username) && $surver_username != ''){
  echo ($survey_username['username']);
}else{
  $survey_username = '';
}
```

My advice to you would to learn how to write and understand PHP functions first.

Also take a look at [MySQLi](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-to-use-php-improved-mysqli-extension-and-why-you-should) and [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) tutorials and learn how queries and binding results actually work.

Answer (score 0):

Your database is very likely responding with an error, which you can examine using `mysql_error()`.  That error is because the query is incomplete:

```
SELECT * FROM users_survey WHERE username
```

Your `WHERE` clause doesn't check for anything.  `username` isn't a valid clause.  It would normally be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM users_survey WHERE username = 'some value'
```

With a complete query, results will be returned.  (Which may be 0 results if nothing matches the `WHERE` predicate.)

Comment: changed 'some value' to 'username' because it has to take the username  but still not displaying anything..

Comment: @Armando: Does that query match anything?  If you're specifying `username = 'username'` then it's going to return only records where the `username` column has the exact string value "username".  If there aren't any such columns, it won't return anything.

Comment: I have in the table a colum with usernames This is my other query where i put them in to the table : INSERT INTO users_survey (username )VALUES('{$username}' )"; According to this its putting it into users_survey under $username